# How to get flask request context in celery task?

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have a flask server running within a gunicorn. 
In my flask application I want to handle large upload files (>20GB), so I plan on letting a celery task do the handling of the large file.

The problem is that retrieving the file from `request.files` already takes quite long, in the meantime gunicorn terminates the worker handling that request. I could increase the timeout time, but the maximum file size is currently unknown, so I don't know how much time I would need.

My plan was to make the request context available to the celery task, as it was described here: http://xion.io/post/code/celery-include-flask-request-context.html, but I cannot make it work

**Q1** Is the signature right?

I set the signature with
 `celery.signature(handle_large_file, args={}, kwargs={})`
and nothing is complaining. I get the arguments I pass from the flask request handler to the celery task, but that's it. Should I somehow get a handle to the context here?

**Q2** how to use the context?

I would have thought if the flask request context was available I could just use `request.files` in my code, but then I get the warning that I am out of context.

Using celery 4.4.0

Code:

```
# in celery.py:
from flask import request
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery('celery_worker',
                backend=Config.CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND,
                broker=Config.CELERY_BROKER_URL)

@celery.task(bind=True)
def handle_large_file(task_object, data):
   # do something with the large file...
   # what I'd like to do:
   files = request.files['upfile']
   ...

celery.signature(handle_large_file, args={}, kwargs={})
```

```
# in main.py
def create_app():
   app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0])
   ...
   celery_worker.conf.update(app.config)

   # copy from the blog
   class RequestContextTask(Task):...
   celery_worker.Task = RequestContextTask
```

```
# in Controller.py
@FILE.route("", methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    data = dict()
    ...
    handle_large_file.delay(data)
```

What am I missing?